# jQuery mobile button - highlight when clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, paypal

I've got an order form on a mobile website with PayPal button. The PayPal button is a form with an input=image button.

I had to use data-role='none' to remove the styling of jQuery Mobile because it stretched the button and ruined it's design. But now - I don't have any input to the user that the button has been submitted.

How can I add the highlight to the button without changing it's inherent design?

Thanks!

P.S - the button code is as this:

```
<input type="image" src="<button url>" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" data-role="none">
```

Comment: could we see the image for the button? link to it?

Comment: not really :) it's just an image sized 290x70 (WxH)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to suggest you follow the jQM custom image suggestion to achieve the results you want, but not 100% as the size will be different.

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

> **Custom Icons**
>  To use custom icons, specify a data-icon value that has a unique name like myapp-email and the button plugin will
>   generate a class by prefixing ui-icon- to the data-icon value and
>   apply it to the button: ui-icon-myapp-email.
>
> You can then write a CSS rule in your stylesheet that targets the
>   ui-icon-myapp-email class to specify the icon background source. To
>   maintain visual consistency with the rest of the icons, create a white
>   icon 18x18 pixels ***saved as a PNG-8 with alpha transparency***.
>
> In this example, we're just pointing to a standalone icon image, but
>   you could just as easily use an icon sprite and specify the
>   positioning instead, just like the icon sprite we use in the
>   framework.
>
> ```
> .ui-icon-myapp-email {
>   background-image: url("app-icon-email.png");
> }
> ```
>
> This will create the standard resolution icon, but many devices now
>   have very high resolution displays, like the retina display on the
>   iPhone 4. To add a HD icon, create an icon that is 36x36 pixels
>   (exactly double the 18 pixel size), and add second rule that uses the
>   `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` media query to target a rule only
>   to high resolution displays. Specify the background image for the HD
>   icon file and set the background size to 18x18 pixels which will fit
>   the 36 pixel icon into the same 18 pixel space. The media query block
>   can wrap multiple icon rules:
>
> ```
> @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
>   .ui-icon-myapp-email {
>       background-image: url("app-icon-email-highres.png");
>       background-size: 18px 18px;
>   }
>   ...more HD icon rules go here...
> }
> ```

The important part is saving the image as a PNG-8 with alpha transparency. Then you should be able to theme as well as give the effect of clicking as well.

For Example I just found a eBay transparent image (using the same image for both buttons):

- http://jsfiddle.net/Eg4DW/1/

JS

```
$('#buttonColor').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-btn-up-e').toggleClass('ui-btn-down-e');
});

$('#buttonColor').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-btn-up-e').toggleClass('ui-btn-down-e');
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <button data-role="none" type="button">
            <img src="http://www.virtuescience.com/images/statusicon/ebay/forum_old-48.png" alt="eBay button"/>
        </button>
        <br />
        <button data-role="none" type="button" class="ui-btn-up-e" id="buttonColor">
            <img src="http://www.virtuescience.com/images/statusicon/ebay/forum_old-48.png" alt="eBay button"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>​
```

The first button is just the normal, the second I applied a jQM theme with mouse down/up

Related:

- https://superuser.com/questions/284931/is-there-any-way-to-save-a-png-8-file-with-alpha-transparency-in-photoshop